# How to create a list of files and directories using csh for use in a program

Tags: foreach, csh

I am writing a very small csh script which uses a foreach loop to read a list of files, runs the files through a program called 'rdseed', converting them into another file type, and then outputs the new files.

I am very inexperienced with programming, but so far my script has worked perfectly well, but I need the files to be output into the directory that they are found in.

To be more specific, I have a file in: /home/Jesse/seajadedata/LandStations/Test/20100902/, however I have several other subfolders in the Test directory. I am running my csh script from the '/Jesse' directory, and all of the new output files are subsequently placed in the '/Jesse' directory, which disorganizes all of the files. There is an option on the program, 'rdseed' that allows an output directory to be specified, so what I would like to do is write the program so that my list of files is associated with a list of the directories that they are found in, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/csh

set startdir=/home/Jesse/seajadedata/LandStations/Test
foreach file(`find $startdir -type f -name "*.*.S.*"`)
rdseed -d -q $outputdir -f $file
end
```

As you can see, I have written $outputdir where the output directory needs to be specified. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Nicely asked question! I believe you'll want to use `dirname` and `basename` to get the directory and filename, respectively, of each path you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should write it as an answer, huh. Try:

```
rdseed -d -q `dirname $file` -f `basename $file`
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch. My script ended up being a bit more complicated in the end, but you gave me a great start. I had no idea about the dirname and basename functions.